# Is it possible to create a JSON Schema that can validate a hashmap / dictionary as opposed to an object?

Tags: dictionary, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

So if I have an object, let's call it a Person, like:

```
{
  "email": "foo@bar.com",
  "first"" "foo",
  "last": "bar"
}
```

This Person object can all be validated quite well with JSON Schema.  The issue is when multiple of these are arranged into a dictionary where the email field is used as the key and the object is the value.  For example:

```
{
  "foo@bar.com": {
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "first"" "foo",
    "last": "bar"
  },
  "you@your.com": {
    "email": "you@your.com",
    "first": "Bob",
    "last": "Bobton"
  },
  "me@mine.com": {
    "email": "me@mine.com",
    "first": "Deb",
    "last": "Debbington"
  }
}
```

This is a common way to structure data.  Beyond the validation of the Person values, which can be handled well by a JSON Schema, there are a number of validations that would be useful on the dictionary:

- The key is an email and can be validated as one.
- The value is always a Person.
- The key is always identical to the value's email field.
- All the keys are unique.

Is it possible to implement these dictionary validations using JSON Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two requirements, yes.
You can use `patternProperties`.

The other two you ask are not possible using JSON Schema. Sorry.

My expectation would be you receive the data in the first form from an API, validate, then map reduce to your desired structure.

Comment: I added pattern property and type to implement the first two requirements.  As you say, I have found nothing in the JSON Schema standard (at 0.7 draft) that would validate the last two points.